# Boost error building catkin on OS X

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, boost, osx, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running step *2.1.3 Building the catkin Workspace* of http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source produces the following error (on OS X 10.8.2). It looks like it's a problem interfacing with BOOST?

```
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/draw_square.dir/tutorials/draw_square.cpp.o
usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.53.0/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hp:50: Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"
make[2]: *** [include/turtlesim/moc_turtle_frame.cxx] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/turtlesim_node.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX executable /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/turtlesim/lib/turtlesim/turtle_teleop_key
[ 88%] Built target turtle_teleop_key
Linking CXX executable /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/turtlesim/lib/turtlesim/mimic
[ 88%] Built target mimic
Linking CXX executable /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/turtlesim/lib/turtlesim/draw_square
[ 88%] Built target draw_square
make: *** [all] Error 2

 /opt/ros/groovy/env.sh make -j8 -l8

Command failed, exiting.
```

Any suggestions, people? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56056/boost-error-building-catkin-on-os-x/) by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-23**:
I am using boost 1.49 on OSX, which is what I believe Groovy is build for, you can try that out but I am not sure if it will work ...

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-24**:
@Hansg91: I could try that yeah, although I'd prefer the latest version of Boost be available (via brew) normally...

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-24**:
I seem to have isolated the error: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22829. Will report back soon!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-25**:
Safer to use the boost version ROS was built and tested with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has already been fixed in source:

https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/pull/6

UPDATE:

To get ros_tutorials from source into your workspace:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/workspace
$ rm -rf src/ros_tutorials src/roscpp_tutorials src/rospy_tutorials src/turtlesim
$ cd src
$ git clone https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials.git
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make_isolated --install
```

That should get the ros_tutorials packages from source. (this may or may not work if there have been breaking changes in other packages which affect ros_tutorials)

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-25**:
Okay, that's great. How do I install from source though? Are their instructions parallel to the ones I linked to above?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-02-25**:
You'll have to remove the packages affected from your workspace and fetch them from source instead. Currently there isn't any easy way to do this. I'll update my answer with instructions.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-25**:
Thanks @William. I'll give that a go now and report back.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-03-25**:
@William that might be the case with me. After I cloned `ros_tutorials`, I still got stuck at "Failed to process package 'roscpp_tutorials'". Removing the entire `ros_tutorials` worked it around. Then I cloned it again but same problem.

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2013-05-22**:
It seems like @William's update moved the location of 'roscpp_tutorials' which causes the rebuild to fail. I had to 'rm -rf build_isolated' before running the build command for it to work. There is probably a less nuclear option, but that worked for me.